# php query adding a div between every third item echod to page

Tags: php, html

I cant seem to figure out how to implement any examples I found online of how to us a counter so that ever 3rd echo of " $row['item']" has a div in between it.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo  $row['item'] ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to do something every x loops, I find the easiest method is to use a [modulo/modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
{
    if($i%3==0)
    {
        echo "This is the third time round...";
    }
}
```

you can easily implement this into a loop while fetching rows from the database.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table")
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
    echo  $row['item'] ;
    if($i%3==0)
    {
        echo "Do your DIV stuff here...";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: @user2055697 I added an example into the answer of how to do it in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from table")
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{
    echo  $row['item'] ;
    if($i%3==0)
    {
        echo "<div>Your div content</div>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

I would also suggest to go through `for/while/foreach` loop as well

Comment: If this isn't a carbon copy of [Fluffeh's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130337/1415724) then I don't know what is. This is what we call *"dirty pool"*, where I come from.

Comment: @Fluffeh LOL! It's nice to see that you've a sense of humour :)) well you do have a point there ;-) "close but no cigar"